# Link Types Missing From Data Warehouse

Tags: tfs

As the title suggests, I've got a problem I just cant find a solution to. I've googled every possible angle and just cant seem to find a solution to this problem.

Basically, I'm missing 2 Link Types -- Affects and Affected By

All the others are there.

For example if i was to create a new Bug WI go to All Links -> Link To there is no option for Affects or Affected By.

Ive checked the data warehouse and the Work Item Link Type Dimension for the cube in analysis services, and they are in fact not in there.

I've tried everything i cn think of,

Ive also exported the linktypes from one of our development environments (which includes the link types) and imported them back into the production server using witadmin... This did not work,

I'm really lost with this one and there just doesn't seem to be any solutions on google, which i find hard to believe but i've spent the last 4 hours looking.

I would really appreciate it if some one could provide some help on this one, im willing to try anything.

It just seems strange why just these 2 link types would be missing.

We use our own process template which is just an extension to the MSF For Agile Software development v5.0 process template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only way to solve this issue is to force TFS to recreate the Tfs_Warehouse database and reprocess the cube..... PROBLEM SOLVED